# Convert video files from mkv to mp4 w/ AC3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

The new spatial audio feature came out on the airpods and I'd like to convert my current 5.1 mkv files to mp4 files with AC3, since it is the only file format supported for spatial audio. I'm unfamiliar with ffmpeg, and would like help on how to convert my files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is everywhere on the internet, for example [there](https://superuser.com/questions/215430/would-like-to-change-audio-codec-but-keep-video-settings-with-ffmpeg).

You should use the `acodec` option to set your audio codec and the `vcodec` option to set your video codec. `copy` means you keep the same as the input.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec ac3 -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

FYI : ac3 is an audio codec, mp4 is a file format